# Proguard and mapping.txt is not creating

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to create Proguard after signing application in release mode but something happening wrong with me because i am unable to create proguard folder nad mapping.txt inside this.

Here is my code:-

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-dishoomit.txt

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
#To avoid changing names of methods invoked on layout's onClick.
# Uncomment and add specific method names if using onClick on layouts
#-keepclassmembers class * {
# public void onClickButton(android.view.View);
#}
#To maintain custom components names that are used on layouts XML:
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}
#Keep classes that are referenced on the AndroidManifest
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface org.apache.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

   <proguard>
                    @${proguard.config}
                    -injars       ${project.jars}
                    -outjars      "${obfuscated.jar.file}"
                    -libraryjars  ${android.libraryjars}
                    -dump         "${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/dump.txt"
                    -printseeds   "${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/seeds.txt"
                    -printusage   "${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/usage.txt"
                    -printmapping "${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/mapping.txt"
  </proguard>
```

I don't understand why i am unable to create it. Please give me some hint or reference.

Answer (score 1):

With Ant, you should see some output from ProGuard in your build log. You'll then get a file bin/proguard/mapping.txt in your project.

With Eclipse, you won't see any build log, but if ProGuard is enabled you'll get a file proguard/mapping.txt in your project.